# unable to create jenkins jobs for maven projects

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to create `jenkins` jobs for `maven` project each having their own `pom.xml` file.

These projects are on a single repository on Git.

While configuring the jenkins jobs I provided the Git repo URL and the location of the `pom.xml` file of the project I want to build (say project `javautils`); however I am getting the below error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project javautils:
  Could not resolve dependencies for project com.modules:javautils:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
  Failed to collect dependencies at com.modules:logging:jar:[0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,):
  No versions available for com.modules:logging:jar:[0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,)
  within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

I need to create seperate jobs for each project however they all are from the same repository

I am unable to find a way to fix this as I am new to jenkins

Comment: Are these dependencies in a private maven repo and if yes have you specified this repo either in pom.xml or settings.xml?

Comment: Yes this has been specified in the pom.xml file. The builds are sucessful when issuing a maven install on Eclipse but fails as a Jenkins job

Comment: and you have deployed the dependdency to the private repo?

Comment: The developers at my company have set this up and I am trying to create build jobs to automate the builds and this is how the pom file looks like

Comment: This is the POM file contents if that helps :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.eprojecta.modules</groupId>
 <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Logging</name>
 <description>Logging</description>
<properties>
  <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
  <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
  <java.version>9</java.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>

Comment: Looks like the dependency is not available. Probably the developers have the dependency just on their local machine.

Comment: Is there a way I can add them to make the jobs run

Comment: Build that dependency from source first and deploy it to the local maven repository (`install` goal).